# Почему g++ (MinGW-w64) не знает про conio.h и не видит _beginthread из process.h?

Tags: c++, windows, компиляция, g++, mingw-w64

Компилятор - g++ из MinGW-w64 (https://cygwin.com/install.html).

В `process.h` есть функция `_beginthread()`. [(docs.microsoft.com)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=vs-2019). При компиляции `g++ -o app.exe app_source.cpp` выдаётся ошибка:

```
C:\xcvbnm>g++ -o app.exe appsource.cpp
appsource.cpp: In function 'void thread_proc_example(void*)':
appsource.cpp:14:2: error: '_endthread' was not declared in this scope
  _endthread();
  ^~~~~~~~~~
appsource.cpp:14:2: note: suggested alternative: '_hread'
  _endthread();
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _hread
appsource.cpp: In function 'int main(int, TCHAR**)':
appsource.cpp:21:2: error: '_beginthread' was not declared in this scope
  _beginthread( thread_proc_example, 0, 0 );
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
appsource.cpp:21:2: note: suggested alternative: 'OpenThread'
  _beginthread( thread_proc_example, 0, 0 );
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  OpenThread

C:\xcvbnm>
```

Вторая проблема - g++ не знает про `conio.h`. Что со всем этим можно сделать? И как компилировать в g++ код, хорошо работающий в Visual Studio?

Пример кода, который не компилируется:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

void __cdecl thread_proc_example( void* param )
{
    _endthread();
    return;
}

int main( int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "String 01\n", "String 02\n", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    _beginthread( thread_proc_example, 0, 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну функции с _ почти всегда не вхлдят в стандарт и непереносимы. Conio.h по большому счету устарело. А что именно от этого заголовочного файла надо?

Comment: Напомню, что `conio.h` специфичен только для windows, а вот `process.h` для unix-подобных систем. В вашей ситуации, (если вы хотите использовать именно эти заголовочные файлы), придётся выбирать, либо `conio.h`, либо `process.h`. И ещё, насколько мне известно, в mingw вообще `process.h` нет, зато он есть в msys2.

Comment: Из `conio.h` используется `_getch()`, из `process.h` используется `_beginthread()` и `_endthread()`. Что всё это можно в принципе сделать на API - это само собой, но даже на гитхабе не мало исходников, одновременно подключающих оба модуля. То есть чтобы что-то собрать, всё придётся переписывать на WinAPI, `CreateThread`, и ручную работу с консолью?

Comment: Если говорить о потоках, то есть 2 пути, использовать msys2 (там есть `process.h`), либо использование `CreateThread`. А про консоль, я как-то давно написал [библиотеку](https://github.com/Centrix14/coniox) для подобных целей, там есть аналог `_getch()`, называется `readKb()`.

Comment: А есть ли возможность "дистрибутив", если это можно так назвать, msys2, включающий gcc, устанавливать локально, а не по сети? MinGW-w64 в поставке cygwin во многом был выбран благодаря возможности локальной установки. (Там в установщике есть опция загрузки в локальную директорию, а затем это можно из локальной директории установить). Или может мне тогда сразу на clang перебираться? P.S.А есть ли книжка, системно излагающая, как пользоваться g++, clang'ом, и прочим, и вообще, как, например, собирать тот же curl из исходников, тем тулчейном, который у них на сайте указан, без VS? P.P.S. Спасибо!

Comment: @SkyDatter, Советую прислушаться к ответу данному zed.

Answer (score 1):

> Компилятор - g++ из MinGW-w64 (https://cygwin.com/install.html)

Код из вашего примера замечательно компилируется в MinGW-w64 (и там есть так же и `conio.h`), но по указанной вами ссылке **НЕ** MinGW-w64.

Дело в том, что под Windows есть 2 порта gcc: один идёт в составе Сygwin, а второй полностью самостоятельный - MinGW-w64 (http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) (его же использует [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/)).

MinGW-w64 можно установить тремя способами:

- через онлайн установщик
- скачав архив
- установив окружение msys2

Онлайн установщик и архивы можно найти здесь: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/

Соответственно, рекомендую забыть про Cygwin и использовать более современные MinGW-w64 и MSYS2.